# Has Safari stopped forwarding link URLs to system services when using the link's context menu?

Tags: safari, services, url, shortcut-menu, links

I seem to recall being able to right-click a link in Safari and use a system service from the context menu in order to send the actual link target URL to the service in question.

Nowadays when right-clicking a link i Safari (13.1) the link's title/text is selected automatically, and when I try to use a service that way it always receives the selected text instead and fails to locate the resource. The services are definitely not receiving the URL since if I use a service with a strict constraint of only accepting URL formatted text, then they don't show up at all in the menu; I have to follow the link and right-click the URL in the address bar before they appear.

I'm wondering if this ever worked like in my first description? If so, what has changed, if anything? Did I change something? Can I get it back?

*MacOS Mojave 10.14.6*

Comment: @IconDaemon Sorry, added at the bottom.

Comment: I'm running Safari 14 and Mojave x.6. I see quite a lot of Services available when I right click. Most of them seem to do nothing, or are illogical from a practical standpoint, like Open man Page in Terminal or Show in Finder. The only service which actually does something is Search With Google. Which Service doesn't run as expected?

Comment: @IconDaemon They all run as can be expected from their input, hence they can be simplified away. Their inputs are the textual content of the `<a>` element, as opposed to the content of its `href` attribute, which is solely in the control of Safari.